# Cannot import a csv file by using read.csv into R

Tags: r, read.csv, import-csv

I'm newbie to R.
I'm trying to import a CSV file on my macbook to R console (R desktop that I installed on my macbook).

I set the wd as "/Users/macbook/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/3. GOOLE ANALYTIC PROGRAM/Cyclistic_Bike_Analytic" (a folder on my macbook).

Then I wrote a code as:
2022_10 <- read.csv("202210-divvy-tripdata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ","). Because I set wd already so I did not put **full path** of the file 202210-divvy-tripdata.csv on the code.

After that I run the code and the error appear as **"Error: unexpected input in "2022_"**

Does any one know what happen here and can u suggest to me how to fix this error :(?

I spent hours to search and watch youtuble video but no answer are specific to my case.

I want to fix this error so I can work with this large file and keep going with my capstone project.

Thank everyone for spending your time in advance

Comment: The error is due to using a number as the first character of the variable. You can run ?make.names in the console to learn more about variable name restrictions.

Comment: Ogm, Thank @Tyler. Your cmt worked for me. I changed the way I name of the variable and then I can do it now.

U save my life time lol

Comment: Thank @Dave2e too for supporting me.